# CSS / React Help - position text infront of image

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using an image and trying to position some text in front of the image and center, as seen in the screenshot from my design below:

[image]

I'm using the below code and found out how to layer the text over the top with z-index, but I'm wondering **how I can center the text inside the parent div as seen in the design?**

Code:

```
<div style={{ display: `flex`, flexDirection: `column` }}>
    {/* image and title */}
    <div>
      <StaticImage
        src="../images/home.png"
        width={1000}
        quality={100}
        formats={["auto", "webp", "avif"]}
        alt="home image"
        style={{ marginBottom: `1rem`, zIndex: `1` }}
      />
      <div style={{
            position: `absolute`,
            top: `50%`,
            left: `50%`,
            transform: `translate(-50%, -50%)`,
            zIndex: `2`,
            display: `flex`,
            justifyContent: `spaceBetween`,
            flexDirection: `row`
          }}>
        <h1 style={{
            color: `white`,
            fontSize: `7vw`
          }}>Gareth</h1>
        <h1 style={{
            color: `white`,
            fontSize: `7vw`
          }}>Veale</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this gives me the text centered on the entire page i think? Perhaps due to the 50% top/left properties?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you should set a width to the parent div to see the difference in flex alignment.

See the code below.

```
<div style={{ display: `flex`, flexDirection: `column` }}>
{/* image and title */}
<div>
  <StaticImage
    src="../images/home.png"
    width={1000}
    quality={100}
    formats={["auto", "webp", "avif"]}
    alt="home image"
    style={{ marginBottom: `1rem`, zIndex: `1` }}
  />
  <div style={{
        position: `absolute`,
        top: `50%`,
        left: `10%`,
        width: `80%`,
        transform: `translate(-50%, -50%)`,
        zIndex: `2`,
        display: `flex`,
        justifyContent: `spaceBetween`,
        flexDirection: `row`
      }}>
    <h1 style={{
        color: `white`,
        fontSize: `7vw`
      }}>Gareth</h1>
    <h1 style={{
        color: `white`,
        fontSize: `7vw`
      }}>Veale</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i just changed the `left` and `width` parameters to get the expected result. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: If my answer was correct please consider setting it as Correct answer